# Making an app in Qt, under LGPL, Can I sell it?

Tags: licensing, qt4, lgpl

I will be developing an application in Qt, using Qt under the LGPL license. Can I sell it to a client, without providing  the source code for it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LGPL allows you to link to the code without releasing your source, so yes, you can do it.

Comment: Awesome, you have really helped a lot, you don't know that, just saved me from licensing visual studio, which I really didn't like in the first place, but its cheaper than the Qt commercial license.
Thanks again!

Comment: Glad that this helped. Well, it's the main difference between GPL and LGPL: LGPL libraries can be used anywhere, including proprietary software, while GPL can't.